# Set time portion of a datetime variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am working on a query that will be an automated job.  It needs to find all the transactions between 8 PM and 8 PM for the last day.  I was thinking of doing something like this

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME

SET @start_date = DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())
SET @end_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

For an automated query this works good at figuring out the date portion.  But the TIME portion of the variable is the current time that the query executes.  Is there a quick simple way to hard code the time portion of both variables to be 8:00 PM?

Comment: +1 I've seen a new approach to this problem with cyberkiwi's answer that I wouldn't have gone without your question. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME

SET @start_date = DATEADD(hour, 20, DATEDIFF(DAY, 2, GETDATE()))
SET @end_date = @start_date + 1

select @start_date, @end_date
```

Comment: Be careful with this. It might not give the correct result if two days ago falls in a different month, especially when the previous month has 31 or 28 days.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy Did you know you can easily test? Change GETDATE() to say '2016-11-01 12:34' which satisfies your "two days ago falls in different month" condition and check the result.

Answer (score 10):

This will also work:

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime
DECLARE @end_date datetime

SET @start_date = LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()), 120), 11) + N'20:00:00'
SET @end_date = @start_date + 1

select @start_date, @end_date
```

Although cyberkiwi's answer is very clever! =)

Comment: Upvoted, as this method makes it very easy to set all sections of the time portion at once. My requirement was to set the time to 23:59:59 (the end of day passed into a stored proc)  SET @start_date = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@start_date,121),10) + ' 23:59:59'

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pull a date from the database and append 3:00 Pm to it. I did it this way

```
select dateadd(hour, 15, datediff(day, 0, myDatabaseDate)) 
from dbo.myDatabaseTable
where myDatabaseId = 1
```

The result that it returned was `2017-10-01 15:00:00.000`. The date in the database is `2017-10-01`. The solution that I proposed was to keep my current date. I added 0 days to my existing date. I gave it 15:00 hours and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In case of just updating a particular part of the datetime you can use `SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS` like:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(MyDate), MONTH(MyDate), DAY(MyDate), <HoursValue>, <MinutesValue>)
```

In other cases it may be required to copy parts of datetime to other or update only certain parts of the datetime:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(MyDate), MONTH(MyDate), DAY(MyDate), DATEPART(hour, MyDate), DATEPART(minute, MyDate))
```

Refer [SQL Server Date/Time related API references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more such functions

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to convert time datatype into datetime and add

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME, @time time
SET @date='2023-10-01'

SET @time='15:00:00'
SET @date=@date+CAST(@time AS DATETIME)
SELECT @date AS DATETIME
```

The result is **2023-10-01 15:00:00.000**

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 20, DATEADD(MINUTE, 00, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))) - 2
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 20, DATEADD(MINUTE, 00, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))) - 1
```

Notes:

- `GETDATE() + X` is the equivalent of `DATEADD(DAY, X, GETDATE())`.
- Converting a `DATEIME` to a `DATE` and then back to a `DATETIME` again sets the time to midnight i.e. `00:00:00.000`.
- Seperate `SET` and `DECLARE` statements are unnecessary, but just in case it helps later, variables may be set as part of a `SELECT` statement too.

Answer (score -2):

I had to do something similar, create a procedure to run from a certain time the previous day to a certain time on the current day.

This is what I did to set the start date to 16:30 on the previous day, basically subtract the parts you don't want to get them back to 0 then add the value that you want it to be.

```
-- Set Start Date to previous day and set start time to 16:30.00.000

SET @StartDate = GetDate()
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(dd,- 1, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(hh,- (DatePart(hh,@StartDate))+16, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(mi,- (DatePart(mi,@StartDate))+30, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(ss,- (DatePart(ss,@StartDate)), @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(ms,- (DatePart(ms,@StartDate)), @StartDate)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then flag / vote to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* Duplicate answer found [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/41609720/2747593).