# How to calculate a date after 1 month currentDate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

How can I calculate a date after a month of current date.

Example if I have 19/04/2012 I want to get 19/05/2012. Is there any function on sql that allows doing this?

I need to do the same for a year also like 19/04/2012 and set 19/04/2013

Cheers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use 
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )

as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Examples (thanks to DarrenDavis)

for month:

```
 select dateadd(m, 1, getdate())
```

for year:

```
 select dateadd(YY, 1, getdate())
```

Comment: is it possible to have a date with a specif hour, like 1 month after but time has to be 4 pm, so will be 2012-04-19 16:00:00

Comment: you can try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952207/set-time-portion-of-a-datetime-variable

Comment: Sorry coming back to you I have the followin Set @EndDate= DATEADD(m, 1, @StartDate)      
Set @EndDate = DATEADD(hour, 17, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@EndDate)) if I do this way it doesnt work but if I add the same but inside update statment it works.Do you know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [dateadd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function

```
SELECT dateadd(mm, 1, '19-Apr-2012')
```

Answer (score 1):

To add 1 month to the current date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, 1, GETDATE())
```

To add 1 year to the current date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YY, 1, GETDATE())
```

For additional arguments see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateAdd:

```
select dateadd(m, 1, getdate())
select dateadd(yy, 1, getdate())
```

search online for other period indicators such as hour, minute, etc!

Comment: This would not work:  SELECT DATEADD(Y, 1, GETDATE())  - It needs to be YY

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job

SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '2012-04-19')

for a year

SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, '2012-04-19')

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for 1 month ahead date . This query works fine in oracle.

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate),1) from dual;
```

For 1 year ahead date use this query

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate),12) from dual;
```

Comment: This question is aimed at SQL Server (as tagged) - There is no SQL Server add_months function and no dual table.