# SQL - set time to tomorrow at 8AM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to take in any date where the time occurs after 12PM and set it to 8AM the next day.

I know how to add a time or hours to a date using `DATEADD`, but not how to just set it to the next day at a specific time.

Trying to use SQL Server / Transact-SQL.

The only way i can think to do this is to create a function that evaluates the date and returns a `DATEADD` to the hour based on the input to get it to 8AM.

Comment: You can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952207/set-time-portion-of-a-datetime-variable

Comment: I don't think I'm misunderstanding the SQL there but i don't think thats quite right for what i was looking for, but thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME = '2015-03-07 16:59:59.997'

SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @mydate), '08:00:00'))
```

produces this output:

```
2015-03-08 08:00:00.000
```

If you also want to check if the datetime value is after 12PM then you can use:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN CAST(@mydate AS TIME) > CAST('12:00:00' AS TIME) THEN 
              DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @mydate), '08:00:00'))
          ELSE 
              @mydate
       END
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i had the checking part figured out, just needed to produce the right output.